# Add UINavigationController to UIViewController using Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

As my question looks simple to all the readers but it's making me mad because I have never used Interface  builder till now. Through coding I am able to achieve it but by using IB i am not.
Here is how i linked.

[image]

[image]

These how I am showing the viewcontroller

```
JBRSettingsRootViewController *settingController = [[JBRSettingsRootViewController alloc]init];

[self presentModalViewController:settingController animated:NO];

[settingController release];
```

Comment: did u connect delegate and datasource of navigation controller to file's owner

Comment: Not totally sure but shouldn't the navigation controller be the root view controller?

Comment: @efrank delegate no. what is this datasource.

Comment: @Thomas sorry I din't get you..

Comment: @Vince adding UINavigationController to UIViewController (i.e JBRSettingsRootViewController)

Comment: @Anand anand can i know what based application did u take. i have taken window based application and when i drag a navigation controller to the resources window and right click on navigation controller i am able to see delegate ,view ,searchDisplayController where i am assigning delegate to file's owner

Comment: @efrank I have took view Based application. I don't want to add navigation controller at didFinishLaunching. I need to add navigation controller to a specific view controller